# Adding files to VS2012 project template?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project-template

I am creating a VS2012 project template for a C++ console app, that is customized to the companies needs.

One of the things is that it needs to have a custom .props file, which I added to the .zip file that VS creates when you export a template based on an existing project.

However, it seems that adding this file to the zip and mentioning it in the `<ProjectItem>` tag within the .vstemplate file, does not make VS realize when basing a project off this template that it should also *copy* this file.

How can I add files to a custom VS2012 project template and also make sure VS copies them to any project based off it?